# MongoDB on external drive

Tags: mongodb

I'm running Faronics DeepFreeze on my PC, which means every time I reboot, I lose all data and changes made to my PC since last startup. Does MongoDB store any information locally, specific to each external database? That is, if I create an external DB then reboot, will I lose any local data that was referencing the external DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongo db install itself in particular directory specified by you and a data folder where it places the data that is again specified by you. So You can install the whole mongo db in external drive. The only thing is you have to set the `mongod` and `mongo` path variable every time you reboot your system since it doesn't persist any of such settings.

Comment: Ok, so the only thing I'll lose is the path I set to the external drive. Any changes I make to the external DB won't result in flags etc being set locally?